# No qualifying bean. Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

У меня возникла небольшая проблема, а именно

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userDAO'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'ru.dao.UserDAO' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4766)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5230)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:698)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:696)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1783)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:293)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:811)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:802)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:460)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:408)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:293)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:811)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:802)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:472)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1472)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1310)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1412)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:360)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:598)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:844)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:721)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
        at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:720)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

UserServiceIpml.java:

```
package ru.services;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import ru.dao.RoleDAO;
import ru.dao.UserDAO;
import ru.models.RoleUser;
import ru.models.User;

import java.util.*;
@ComponentScan("ru")
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    UserDAO userDAO;

    @Autowired
    RoleDAO roleDAO;

    @Autowired
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String login) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userDAO.findByUserName(login);

        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
        }
        return user;
    }

    public boolean saveUser(User user) {
        User userFromDB = userDAO.findByUserName(user.getUsername());

        if (userFromDB != null){
            return false;
        }

        user.setRoles(Collections.singleton(new RoleUser(1L, "ROLE_USER")));
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        userDAO.save(user);
        return true;
    }
}
```

UserDAO:

```
package ru.dao;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import ru.models.RoleUser;
import ru.models.User;

import java.util.Optional;

@Component
@Repository
public interface UserDAO extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    User findByUserName (String userName);
}
```

И SecurityConfig:

```
package ru.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import ru.services.UserServiceImpl;

@ComponentScan("ru")
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    UserServiceImpl userService;
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception{
        httpSecurity
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/coffeeMachine/registration").not().fullyAuthenticated()
                .antMatchers("/coffeeMachine/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/coffeeMachine/user/**").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/coffeeMachine/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/coffeeMachine")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().permitAll().logoutSuccessUrl("/");
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    protected PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(12);
    }

}
```

Может быть кто-нибудь знает, в чём может быть проблема

### UPDATE

после применения EnableJpaRepositories Spring начал выдавать это

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userDAO'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDAO' defined in ru.dao.UserDAO defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on SecurityConfig: Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#4306d148' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#4306d148': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4766)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5230)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:698)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:696)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1783)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:293)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:811)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:802)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:460)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:408)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:293)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:811)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:802)
        at java.management/com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:472)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1472)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1310)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1412)
        at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImp
```

Comment: отпишитесь как попробуете

Answer (score 0):

Т.к. У Вас изначальная проблема с созданием репозитория, а именно с него началася вся данная цепочка:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userService'; 

nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl': 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userDAO'; 

nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type 'ru.dao.UserDAO' available: 

expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. 
Dependency annotations:
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Отсюда видно, что все указанные бины помимо репозитория Spring видит (просто он их создать не может)

Отсюда предположу, что Вам следовало бы включить поддержку репозиториев с помощью аннотации:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "ru.dao")
```

По-хорошему ее лучше ставить над чем-то вроде Persistance Config
Но для начала можете попробовать её и над Application'ом воткнуть(класс с main'ом).
Конкретных рекомендаций в документации по тому где именно ее использовать я не видел.

Чего не скажешь о `ComponentScan`
**Замечание 1:**
Не пытайтесь воткнуть ComponentScan над каждым классом.
Данная аннотация создана для работы с Configuration-классами

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html

**Замечание 2:**
Ставить `@Component` над репозиторием тоже бессмысленно.
Это же интерфейс.
Без конкретных инструкций о том, как его создавать, от чего он зависит и где реализации искать Spring не справится.
А это уже дело Spring Data.

Comment: К сожалению, это только ухудшило ситуацию

Comment: и что же теперь он вам выдает?

Comment: может вы просто до следующей волны ошибок  добрались, которые были скрыты до этого?

Comment: @K_V_G, может у Вас там как раз таки ошибки с настройкой Spring Data.  оттого и репозиторий не создавался?

Comment: Вот, то, что он отправляет

Comment: А если говорить про настройки Spring Data, даже не знаю

Comment: @K_V_G, собственно о чем я и говорил...у вас `entityManagerFactory` нет

Comment: что там у вас еще если честно даже трудно представить - можете куда нибудь в git проект выложить чтобы можно было на все разом посмотреть. (только это надолго поэтому отвечу вечером или ночью если успеете приложить)

Comment: @K_V_G, прочитайте коммент выше ^^^

Comment: @K_V_G если приложите - пинганите меня в комментариях под ответом чтобы я знал

Comment: Хорошо, я сначала попробую добавить entityManagerFactory, а потом приложу git. Спасибо вам за помощь)

Comment: @K_V_G, лучше не надо...выкладывайте как есть...а то может и хуже стать и мы так до нового года не разберемся

Comment: просто тяжело отвечать на вопрос когда ситуация и контекст постоянно меняются

Comment: https://github.com/K-V-G/Spring_CoffeeMachine